# Time-slider in ArcGIS skipping once exported to video

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, timeslider

The set-up: I am using ArcGIS 10.3. I have exactly 528 raster maps in a mosaic dataset. Each one corresponds to the same geography but at different months (from January 1969 to December 2012). I would like to use time-slider to move through these images and export to a video.

The time-slider animates nicely through the rasters inside ArcGIS, but once I try to export it to an .avi video it skips the large majority of images and I end up with only about every sixth raster being displayed.

Potentially relevant: the time-slider is operating on a string field that is the concatenated year and month (YYYYMM format). I created this field using the field calculator. It looks like this:

[image]

I picked this format because it fits one of the options in the Layer Properties dialogue. Note that in this dialogue I do not set the layer time extent because if I have ArcGIS calculate it directly, it decides the time starts at 1/1/0001 for some reason (this is highlighted in the next picture)

[image]

So in the time-slider properties dialogue, I change 1/1/0001 to 1/1/1969 and it seems to work fine. From here, the animation works in ArcGIS.

[image]

Using the default settings (below) to export to video causes the skipping. When I tested the default settings on a smaller subset (24 months) it worked fine. It's hard to test settings on the whole thing since the video usually takes a long time to export (and often doesn't work if I open any windows over the top of it).

[image]

Comment: I think you should take a step back and go to the simplest thing that you tried which was the first one and provide more precise details of what you tried and where you were stuck.  If our expert volunteers can get you past that then the rest of your investigation becomes moot.  What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, without having access to 500 rasters it will be difficult to replicate the issue and help, so go back to step 1. My gut feeling is that it's probably some default setting you want to change in time slider or layer properties. May be Arcmap has set some time step automatically based upon your inputs and you just need to reset it?

Comment: @PolyGeo - thanks for the very good point. I will edit the question significantly to start at the beginning. One question at a time :)

Comment: @HFBrowning , Try to use `Date` field type instead of `text` for your date field to see if it works.

Comment: I was having similar problems, but they resolved when I switched to ArcGIS Pro to export my final animations. If that software is an option, I would use it.

Comment: @MapMan I think you should expand your comment by a sentence or two into an answer.  It is fine to suggest alternative workflows, especially in a case like this where the same licensing would be involved.

Comment: It may seem harsh to close this as non-reproducible but in two months no answers have been offered and so it seems to be unsuited to focussed Q&A without further editing to try an refine it into a series of explicit steps using readily available data that someone could be reasonably expected to volunteer the time to test.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo - that's fine. I basically gave up on it after I got no answers - changing the date to text did not work for me (as Farid suggested) and I don't have access to ArcGIS Pro. At this point I just decided to hackishly export it out about a year at a time (which again, works fine) and then stitch the videos together using a command line tool. I don't know how to make it reproducible as a problem since my data are large and it's kind of specific. Closing is fine with me. Thanks.